# Link different python files with button click using tkinter python 3.4

Tags: python, tkinter

I have multiple files in my project. i want to link different python script with the button click in gui programming.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
two=Button(root,text="button")


root.mainloop()
```

like i have:

```
 1.classes.py  
 2. gui.py 
 3. final.py ..etc in my project directory
```

with the button click i like to open another python file in GUI form 
Example: i like to open classes.py with the button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.system` I've done a bit of searching around and can't figure out how to open the file is python shell, best I can do is notepad

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

def callback():
    filename = 'test.py'
    os.system(filename) #Open file [Same as Right-click Open]
    os.system('notepad '+filename) #Open in notepad

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text="Python File", command=callback).pack()
root.mainloop()
```